# Getting JSF ServletContext in non-request environment in a CDI bean

Tags: jsf, cookies, initialization, cdi

I am using TomEE+ 1.7.1.
With JSF managed beans this code was working well:

```
@ManagedBean( eager = true )
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ServletContext sc = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        if (GlobalSettings.TESTMODE) {
            sc.getSessionCookieConfig().setDomain("." + GlobalSettings.APP_DOMAIN_TEST);
        } else {
            sc.getSessionCookieConfig().setDomain("." + GlobalSettings.APP_DOMAIN);
        }
    }
}
```

The init function ran at application startup and ServletContext was available.

I read everywhere that it's time to migrate to CDI beans instead of JSF beans. So I wanted to change `@ManagedBean( eager = true )` to `@Named @Eager` (@Eager is from Omnifaces). Init function is running at application startup, but there is no FacesContext so I can't get ServletContext.

**General question**: How to get ServletContext in a non-request environment in CDI beans? (ServletContext is not a 'per request' object, so it should exist before the first request.)

**Specific question**: how to set the domain for the session cookies dynamically from code but before the first request occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) for the purpose of performing programmatic configuration on a servlet based application.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext(); 
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext(); 
        // ...
    }

}
```

A `@WebListener` is inherently also CDI managed and thus you can just use `@Inject` and friends in there.

An application scoped managed bean is intented for holding application scoped data/state which can be used/shared across requests/views/sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Per the CDI spec, you can `@Inject` the `ServletContext` into a CDI bean. Just be sure to do it in a `@PostConstruct`, as injected fields are available only after construction:

```
@Inject ServletContext extCtxt;

@PostConstruct
public void doSomething(){
  // do something with your injected field
}
```